# NavController push from subview

Tags: ios, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller, subview

I got an application with a tabbar and a navigation controller for one of the tab view.
The Navigation controller is pushing several views and one of them has a button which permits to add a subview (I am actually displaying a popup message -not an uialert- when pushing that button).

The problem is that I would like now to be able to push a new view controller once I pushed a button in the subview...

I cannot find my navcontroller, even when I use the pushmethod of appdelegate.tabbar.navigationController

Does one of you have easy idea about how to implement that ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: `button.superview.navigationcontroller`?

Answer (score 0):

If the button's press action of the second button is being handled in the same `UIViewController` as the other button's action you should simply be able to use

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];`.

If your subview has it's own `UIViewController` you could add a reference to your first `UIViewController` or to the `navigationController` itself and use it that way.